# Inheriting and aggregating class attributes

Tags: python, django, inheritance, metaclass

A simple example:

```
class A:
    attr = {'a': 1}

class B(A):
    attr = {'b': 2} #overrides A.attr
```

What I want is a method to aggregate the dictionaries. I can think of just these options:

1. Ignore that disconcerting feeling and copy everything by hand.
2. Manually adding the dictionaries:

   ```
   class B(a):
       attr = dict(list(six.iteritems(A.attr)) + list(six.iteritems({
           'b': 2
       })))
   ```

   Note `'b': 2` must come second so its keys shadow `A`'s.

   This must reference `A` explicitly (**is there some way to get this with `super`?**). It also needs this kind of micro inheritance to be applied manually.
3. This is also something that could be achieved with metaclasses. I've seen it [done in `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` in django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L35).
   The idea is to have the metaclass handle dictionary merging for a specific attribute.

   This is far more work. Also, as it introduces magic that doesn't normally happen in python, this might be considered a poor option. I also prefer to not use metaclasses unless necessary to avoid conflicts.

   One major advantage is the user doesn't need to manually aggregate the attribute data.

**Is there another way?**

**I'd like to know what others think of each approach with regard to good programming practice.**

In my case I'm using a [`MultiModelForm` from django-betterforms](http://django-betterforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multiform.html), and have a base form with just a few `ModelForm`s but want to extend it. I don't think the inherited class should need to duplicate the `ModelForm`s in the `form_classes` attribute from the parent.

Should it be up to the user to manage inheritance as in option 2 or should `MultiModelForm` handle it automatically with a metaclass as in option 3? Are there other issues with each option I haven't discussed?

Comment: [In Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), you'll be able to do `attr = {**A.attr, 'b': 2}`.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using [`dictionary.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) function, which will add a new dictionary to an existing one

**Example**

```
>>> class A:
...     attr = {'a': 1}
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     attr = dict(A.attr)
...     attr.update({'b' : 2 })
... 
>>> 
>>> A.attr
{'a': 1}
>>> B.attr
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

**What it does?**

- `attr = dict(A.attr)` returns a new dictionary from `A.attr`. This is important because if we write

  ```
  attr = A.attr
  ```

  we will end up updating the `attr` of `A` class instead of `B` class.
- `attr.update({'b' : 2 })` Updates the `B.attr` by adding the new dictionary `{'b' : 2 }`.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
class A:
    attr = {'a': 1}

class B(A):
    attr = dict({'b': 2}.items() + A.attr.items())
```

Comment: You're right, it does too. I've always thought that was python 3 only. Though it'd reverse the order of the addition.

Comment: @jozxyqk: It's actually Python *2* only; in Python 3, `items` returns a view, and dict views don't support addition. There are changes you can make to adapt it to Python 3, if you really want to.